# how to place red color div on to right upper corner of jquery dialog?

Tags: jquery, css

I having a round corner red background color DIV and a jquery dialog without title bar.

I need to place the red background color DIV on the right upper corner of dialog. What need to do to achieve that? please suggest.

here is the JsFiddle link,

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/6FGqN/753/)

```
$('#open').click(function() {
$('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6FGqN/754/

Comment: need some more downward...half part should inside the dialog.

Comment: I posted my updated answer..check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css:

```
.roundCorner {
width: 150px;
height: 5px;
padding: 2em;
border-bottom:0;
position:relative;
background:red;
left:320px;
top:35px;
z-index:10000;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/6FGqN/757/

Comment: hi, thanks Joke, but I want this DIV title to be open with jquery dailog, not independently. how to replace jquery dialog title with custom DIV?

Comment: how to replace jquery dialog title with custom DIV?

Comment: Check my updated demo..If you find the answer relevant then accept it..:)..I hope you got the solution there..

Comment: sorry, but when i close the dialog the red color DIV still persist.

Comment: i think we need to use, $('#dlg').dialog({/*options*/}).parent().find("div.ui-dialog-titlebar')

Comment: but I am not sure where we need to use it?

Comment: I checked my fiddle..It's working fine..What is the problem that your facing currently?

Comment: hey Joke, the solution works fine, but is there any chance to change the way of displaying red DIV? Instead of show/hid DIV, can we make this DIV part of dialog, kind of replace jquery dialog to DIV (.parent().find("div.ui-dialog-titlebar'), not sure).....and more over how to find top/left position of DIV?

Comment: I asked a separate question related to that... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920372/how-to-change-customstyle-with-roundcorner