# how to change "customStyle" with "roundCorner"?

Tags: css

I below fiddle, how to to replace "customStyle" CSS with "roundCorner" CSS.

"roundCorner" CSS is a curve DIV, also Is there any chance to keep this "roundCorner" DIV partially inside the dialog and partially outside the dialog?

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/6FGqN/760/)

```
<div class="roundCorner" style="display:none;">
Dialog Title
</div>
```

Comment: Huh? Please try to explain yourself a little better.

Comment: currently dialog title applying a class "customStyle". Now I want to place CSS class "roundCorner" (which should apply in DIV/Span), hope clear now.

Comment: $('.customStyle').removeClass('.customStyle').addClass('roundCorner') ???

Comment: `.parent().find('div.ui-dialog-titlebar').addClass('roundCorner');`..is this what your looking for??

Comment: @Joke and hugo, correct, but see my Red corner DIV, is it not displaying correctly on jquery dialog.  http://jsfiddle.net/6FGqN/770/

Comment: moreover I also don't want entire red DIV inside the dialog, it should haft inside and haft outside....

Comment: How you want it to be displayed??Sorry but iam not getting you..

Comment: Yes Joke, need to display similar to this fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/gD49Z/1/       but here entire red DIV inside the dialog, but I want haft inside and haft upside...hope..clear..thanks